# Cannot edit inherited class of IList<T> but works fine with IList reason?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, datagrid, ilist

The title kinda says it all, but let me explain it in more detail with examples.

Lets assume you want to create a CustomList for various reason.

For example:

```
public CustomList<T> : IList<T>
{
   //all members from IList<T> are implemented and are working
}
```

Now you have a DataGrid which binds to this list

In Code behind of a XAML (WPF) file:

```
TestDataGrid.ItemsSource = new CustomList<Person>() { new Person(), new Person() };
```

Now you would assume the editing works fine since the Person class has no retriction what so ever and the IsReadOnly of the CustomList is set to false.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set }
}
```

But wait, the WPF DataGrid gives out the error Message:
'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

Now if I change the implementation of my CustomList to this:

```
public CustomList<T> : IList
{
   //all members from IList are implemented and are working
}
```

The editing works, but the behaviour or LINQ and IEnumerable extensions just sucks, because the GetEnumerator returns a non generic version so I am stuck with only objects and would need to cast to my desired class all the time.

Am I seeing something wrong or is there no good solution?
I just want to have a editable (in WPF DataGrid) CustomList with Sort Functionality (not OrderBy - Sort in place).

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The title doesn't match the code you posted. Could you please double-check your post? Did you mean IList instead of List?

Comment: Sorry and yes I meant IList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some parts of the WPF engine look for [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not `IList<T>`. Since [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not implement `IList`, WPF is only aware that your list is `IEnumerable`, not `IList`. You should implement both interfaces. You should use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) to hide implementations that shouldn't be public on your object, e.g.

```
public class CustomList<T> : IList<T>, IList
{
    // this is the one we want users of this class to use
    public void Add(T value) { ... }
    // IList's implementation; needs to exist, but this way it's hidden,
    // unless you cast to IList
    int IList.Add(object value) { this.Add((T)value); return this.Count - 1; }
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of explicit interface implementation, totally forgot about those.

Answer (score 1):

Implement both interfaces `IList<T>` **and** `IList`, just like `List<T>` does.

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work you probably want your `CustomList` to implement the other required interfaces, like `List<T>` does.  So change from:

```
public CustomList<T> : IList<T>
{
   //all members from IList are implemented and are working
}
```

to

```
public CustomList<T> : IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
{
   //all members from IList are implemented and are working
}
```